# Performance Point: Change the width of an item of the Decomposition tree

Tags: ssas, performancepoint

I need to expand the width of the items on the decomposition tree silverlight control.

There are names in the SSAS cube that need to be shown on the decomposition tree without the need to view the details while hovering above the item.

Is there any way to set the width of an item as a fixed value or as a percentage of the window?

If not can you change the control via Visual Studio project using the existent libraries and expanding their code?

UPDATE: Tried the following

1. Unzipped DecompositionTree.xap
2. Opened the DecompositionTree Core on .Net Reflector
3. Changed the Node.xaml width option with value 100 instead of 120 using Reflexil
4. Repackaged to .xap and uploaded. DecompositionTree stopped Working
5. Repeated 1-4 on the same xap to change the value back to 120 and everything worked well. The Decomposition Tree started working again!!!